# Matrix of Functions

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, functions

I was thinking about a problem and I realized for a family of functions say $L^1([a,b])$ one can define matrices with functions as elements:
$$
A=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
f_{11}& ...&{f_{1n}}\\
& \vdots \\
f_{n1}& ...&{f_{nn}}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and matrix multiplication is done by considering elementwise production over functions. One can see that we can define vectors of functions $f:=[f_1,...,f_n]$ to occupy them with a norm by defining the dot product between two vectors $f$ and $g$ as $f.g=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \int_{a}^{b} f_i(x)g_i(x)$.

I tried to Google this but I couldn't find anything! My question is there any field of mathematics that such matrices are discussed in?

Comment: For the summation, I assume you meant f (sub i) and g (sub i)

Comment: Yes sir. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the functions are in $L^1$ is not enough for the integral  $\int_a^b f_i(x)g_i(x)\,dx$  to converge. If you want your space to have an inner product, assume the functions come from   $L^2$. In which case you have a *vector-valued $L^2$ space*, or $L^2$ space of vector-valued functions. E.g., [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality on vector-valued L2 space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/684982/)

Similarly, one defines matrix-valued  spaces. Some name variants:

- matrix-valued Lebesgue space
- matrix-valued $L^p$ space
- $L^p$ space of matrix-valued functions

and if this is generalized to infinite dimensions, "matrix" is replaced with "operator".

Such spaces are of interest in harmonic analysis and functional analysis. I don't know of a book devoted to Lebesgue spaces in this context (I suspect they don't have enough novel features compared to the scalar case) but you may want to take a look at [Operator Valued Hardy Spaces](http://books.google.com/books/about/Operator_Valued_Hardy_Spaces.html?id=wnzMtntdjgMC) by Tao Mei.

Answer (score 1):

Matrices consisting of function entries are called matrix valued functions, they are studied in [matrix calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) for example. Vectors with function entries are called [vector valued functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_function). In general, if $V$ is a vector space one can define spaces of functions on $[a,b]$ with values in $V$, e.g. $L^2([a,b],V)$ with $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ has the inner product you defined. They are studied in functional analysis.